# Reporting Services: How are the full paths of files in a solution related to each other, and how do I edit the paths?

Tags: reporting-services, relative-path, relativesource, ssrs-2012

In what way are the full paths (the directories where the project files and reports are) of the report files, solution file and project files related to each other in Reporting Services 2012? I tried to rename one of the folders of the solution and open the solution, and the solution understood this, which indicate that the full paths aren't absolute.

I also wonder how to change the 'fullpath' property of the the files, like the project file paths or report file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand? If you are asking if I want to display all my reports so that the user can select one, then you could have a SQL table with your report names in the one column and the path in the other column e.g `/reportservice/ProjectA/Report1`

Let your application display the report, name and when the user makes a select index, let your application pass a user name and password through on your behalf to report server.

Comment: Hi! I made a major clarification of the question, as I realized I didn't fully understand my question myself. Hopefully it is clearer what I mean now. As I understand it you are talking about the deployed reports, whereas I mean the sln-, rdl-files and the like (the source files).